# is this possible? Video playback on ie7 and ie8 without Flash player

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, audiovideoplayback

Is it possible to develop a webpage on which users (most of them use older than ie9 versions) must be able to play a video without enforcing the user to install any plugin or program. Is this a "mission impossible" case at this moment?

Note that I already have tried this: http://html5media.info/
 but with this the older ie browsers must have a flash player plugin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not possible to play media without a plugin on browsers that do not support HTML5 features.  I think your best approach might be to detect, via Modernizr.js or similar, if <video> support is present, and if not, fallback to Flash player.  If the user lacks both Flash and HTML5, then prompt a file download with explanation of how to open the file in windows media player.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is how i solved this problem right now. But I was hoping that someone know a better solution for this problem :(...